# Sorting a vector by unordered map of the elements pointers as keys

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, unordered-map

I have a vector of elements `std::vector<T> my_vec`. At some point in my code I assign a score for each element of the vector using an unordered map. After that, I would like to sort the vector by the scores of its elements with the minimum code possible.

I came up with this solution, define the map as follows: `std::unordered_map<const T*, float> scores_map`. For score assignment, insert the score to the map as follows:

```
for (const auto& el : my_vec)
    scores_map[&el] = calc_score(el);
```

Then I sort using:

```
std::sort(my_vec.begin(), my_vec.end(), 
[&my_map](const auto& a, const auto& b){return my_map[&a] > my_map[&b];});
```

Is this considered a bug-free and good practice, if not any idea how to make it so?

Comment: Elements in vector are moved during sort, so their pointers also change and `scores_map` becomes invalid, isn't it? I don't think there is something better, than sorting `std::vector<std::pair<T, float>>`

Comment: Ouch. you are totally right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@fas wrote in a comment:

> Elements in vector are moved during sort, so their pointers also change and `scores_map` becomes invalid, isn't it?

That is correct. You should not use pointers as keys in `scores_map`.

#### Option 1

If the vector contains unique items, you may use the `T` as the key type.

```
for (const auto& el : my_vec)
    scores_map[el] = calc_score(el);
```

Then sort using:

```
std::sort(my_vec.begin(), my_vec.end(), 
[&my_map](const auto& a, const auto& b){return my_map[a] > my_map[b];});
```

#### Option 2

If the vector does not contain unique elements, you may use the following strategy.

1. Use indices as the key of `my_map`.
2. Create a helper `std::vector<size_t>` object that contains just indices.
3. Sort the vector of indices.
4. Use the sorted indices vector to fetch the elements from `my_vec`.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < my_vec.size(); ++i )
    scores_map[i] = calc_score(my_vec[i]);

// Create the vector of indices
std::vector<size_t> indices_vec(my_vec.size());
for ( size_t i = 0; i < indices_vec.size(); ++i )
{
   indices_vec[i] = i;
}

// Sort the vector of indices
std::sort(indices_vec.begin(), indices_vec.end(), 
[&my_map](size_t a, size_t b){return my_map[a] > my_map[b];}); 


for (auto index : indices_vec)
{
   // Use my_vec[index]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, this not bug-free. `std::sort` will change the addresses of the elements.

You could store the score with each element in a pair:

```
std::pair<float, T>
```

and sort the vector

```
std::vector<std::pair<float, T> > my_vec
```

with

```
std::sort(my_vec.begin(), my_vec.end(), 
    [](const auto& a, const auto& b){return a.first > b.first;});
```

Comment: Just a note that no need to pass lambda if `T`'s can be compared, pairs are sorted lexicographically

Comment: Would using the element itself as a key be considered a good solution or is it an overkill?

Comment: You need a hash function for your class and maybe a key compare function. Do you have a hash function for your class? If yes, you can use it